# Create animated SVG/GIF Image from Adobe Illustrator objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, adobe-illustrator

I would like to create an animated background image for my slider. I also have already the objects which I want to animated (in illustrator). Now I want to have these objects to move randomly across the image. The only point is, I have absolutly no idea on how to do this especially because I want to have exactly this objects to move and not some HTML, JS or CSS created objects. Is there any way to make this possible?

I have already googled for hours and all I can find is either creating CSS/JS objects/particles which then will move randomly or create particles in Illustrator. Isn't it simply possible to have my objects moving around?

There is not even a need of interaction with the mouse or determining of amount of the objects. I just want them to move around randomly.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can export your objects to PNGs / SVGs and write JS to animate them randomly in a loop.

Here is a similar [Example](https://codepen.io/cooljockey/pen/uyeHz). You can replace div elements with your image elements and modify the JavaScript according to your needs.

The following two lines are used to generate random positions with respect to user's viewport.

```
var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
```

If you are not that familiar with coding, you can import your objects (vectors) from your .AI file directly into Adobe Animate, make your animation loop and publish in JavaScript / HTML.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is, you can try websites that animates SVG's, try this link https://www.svgator.com/ you can then export your work as SVG